# spring security config giving error on server startup

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

Hi I have created a security-app-context.xml for my grails/groovy app. It is as follows:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />    
    <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />   
    <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />   
    <intercept-url pattern="/swf/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />   
    <form-login />
    </http>

       <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="password" authorities="supervisor, teller, user" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

I edited my web.xml like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
                 /WEB-INF/security-app-context.xml --> added this
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have added spring-security-acl-3.1.0.M2.jar,spring-security-config-3.1.0.M2.jar,spring-security-core-3.1.0.M2.jar,spring-security-taglibs-3.1.0.M2.jar and spring-security-web-3.1.0.M2.jar in my lib but
I am getting an error on tomcat server startup saying

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] while setting bean property 'securityMetadataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.security.web.util.UrlMatcher]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [org.springframework.security.web.util.UrlMatcher]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'org.springframework.security.web.util.UrlMatcher'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [org.springframework.security.web.util.UrlMatcher]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
.........and some other exceptions
```

I have installed the spring security core plugin, the authorities in security-app-context.xml need to be defined somewhere?
Not sure where am I missing if anything, I followed the spring security tutorial..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What tutorial did you follow? You don't configure *any* XML when using the spring-security-core plugin, it handles the bean registration and makes the additions to web.xml for you.

See http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/

Comment: followed this tutorial :http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html  , basically plugin is used to create annotation based roles but right now I need to restrict access to static content folders (js,css,images,swf)to authenticated users only

Comment: That's fine, you can wire things up the traditional way if you prefer. But you need to pick one; the plugin is incompatible with that approach, and there's no way to get them to work together.

Comment: Ok, that definitely makes sense..I need to know if I can achieve the static contents folder restriction using the plugin, if so how do I go about doing it? and where do I specify them?

Answer (score -1):

Your web.xml is wrong, you should specify only one url in context-param.param-value